# How to integrate Mustache template engine into Phalcon PHP application?

Tags: mustache, phalcon

How to integrate Mustache template engine into Phalcon PHP 3 application to use it instead of built-in volt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best idea is to use `composer` in order to get Phalcon Incubator - a set of extra Phalcon-integrated libraries which contains also the Mustache implementation.

How to do that:

1. Install Composer in our project (or globally)

   `curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
2. Create composer.json with following content:

   `{
       "require": {
           "phalcon/incubator": "~3.0"
       }
   }`

   If you're using Phalcon 2.0.x use instead:

   `{
       "require": {
           "phalcon/incubator": "~3.0"
       }
   }`
3. Run composer install command:

   `php composer.phar install`
4. Add composer autoloader somewhere in your project using for instance:

   `require_once APP_PATH . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

   I usually add this line to `config/loader.php`, but it depends on your project structure.
5. Set mustache as your renderer in view component

   ```
   //Setting up the view component
   $di->set('view', function() {

       $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();

       $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');

       $view->registerEngines(
           ['.mhtml' => 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Mustache']
       );

       return $view;
   });
   ```

And that's it, you're done.

You can read more on [Incubator github page](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator) and [Mustache implementation page](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Mvc/View/Engine).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, using Incubator here:

https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Mvc/View/Engine

Comment: Always check the incubator first :)